# stick navigation to top when scrolled to/past - Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navigation that sticks to the top of my site when it hits the top of the page. (the navigation is 280px from the top when user is at top of the page)I am using Bootstrap 3 framework in Wordpress.

This is a common thing and I have found a number of examples but can't seem to get it to work for me.

I have the generic Bootstrap navigation. I am trying to put the following code in with no success.

HTML ( in my < head > tags )

```
<script>
  $('#nav').affix({
  offset: {
    top: $('header').height()
  }
  });   
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> >

<header class="masthead">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <h1><a href="#" title="scroll down for your viewing pleasure">Bootstrap 3 Layout Template</a><p class="lead">Big Top Header and Fixed Sidebar</p></h1>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</header>           


<!-- Begin Navbar -->
<div id="nav">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
       <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>        
   </div>
  </div><!-- /.navbar -->
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
header {
  height:280px;
}

#nav.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Apart from the fact you're missing 2 closing </div> tags at the end your html, it works fine for me.

Comment: It doesn't stick for me? I thought it was the code I put in my < head > tags but I can't figure it out

Comment: Try removing the `<?php body_class(); ?>`